# Previously working EC2 ssh hangs when trying to connect at 'Sending environment...'

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that has been around for a few months, I was able to ssh in then but I haven't used it in a while and now I can't. Here is the debug output, at the end after the line `debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8` it just stalls indefinitely.

```
ssh -vT -i ~/.ssh/lambdaTools-temp.pem ec2-user@ec2-52-3-65-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/nhahn/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/nhahn/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-3-65-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com [52.3.65.199] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/nhahn/.ssh/lambdaTools-temp.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/nhahn/.ssh/lambdaTools-temp.pem-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/nhahn/.ssh/SqorAgain.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/nhahn/.ssh/SqorAgain.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-52-3-65-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Hr+Y5O57rjABvZsydfKZcJmtXdE+cbFF0aZRUUNireU
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-52-3-65-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com,52.3.65.199' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/nhahn/.ssh/lambdaTools-temp.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-52-3-65-199.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([52.3.65.199]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
^Cdebug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Killed by signal 2.
```

Comment: why are you using -T?

Comment: I copied the command from somewhere, but yeah that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Removed the -T command as per Christian Cerri's comment, it worked.